# Destroying the result of two subtracted arrays of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, rspec

A little bit of background:

Every product has a set of variants, the amount of variants a product has should change depending on its attributes.

A method called find_valid_variants returns the variants that the product should have, this is then passed to the destroy_redundant_variants method which is supposed to destroy any variants that the product has but are not included in the valid_variants.

```
def self.find_valid_variants(product)
    product.product_options.blank? ? options = [nil] : options = product.product_options
    product.product_sides.blank? ? sides = [nil] : sides = product.product_sides
    product.product_sizes.blank? ? sizes = [nil] : sizes = product.product_sizes

    valid_variants = []

    sides.product(sizes, options).each do |side, size, option|
        valid_variants << Variant.where(product_id: product.id, product_side_id: side, product_size_id: size, product_option_id: option)
    end
    valid_variants
end

def self.find_redundant_variants(product)
    destroy_redundant_variants(product, find_valid_variants(product))
end

def self.destroy_redundant_variants(product, valid_variants)
    (product.variants - valid_variants).each { |valid_variant| valid_variant.destroy }
end
```

The problem is that the method destroys all of the products variants when in my test case it should only destroy 2.

Here is the Rspec test:

```
it "destroys the redundant variants" do
    @product = Fabricate(:product, product_size_ids: ["#{@product_size.id}", "#{@product_size_2.id}"], product_options_attributes: [{name: 'Rounded', description: 'Add a round edge'}, {name: 'None', description: 'Nothing'}])
    @product.variants.count.should == 4
    @product.product_options.each { |p| p.destroy }
    @product.reload
    ProductVariationService.find_redundant_variants(@product)
    @product.variants.count.should == 2
end
```

Comment: Is there some reason you're not showing the definition of `find_redundant_variants`? Is that not relevant?

Comment: @peter I have updated the question to include `find_redundant_variants`.

Comment: Sorry, but your code is too confusing to walk through readily. I'd suggest using a debugger to examine whether `valid_variants` is returning all the variants and, if so, why. I would also check the value of `@product.variants.count` immediately prior to your call to `find_redundant_variants`.